# MySQL Database connected to Android App (Java) by web Address/hostname

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio, jdbc

I wanted to connect my MySQL Database (which runs on my Raspberry) with my android app (written in java) by using the "mysql-connector.jar" library.

When I use the ip address to connect it with my app, everything will work.

```j
    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:3306/databasename";
    private static final String user = "username";
    private static final String pass = "password";
```

However, if I will use the web address/hostname (made with noip.com) instead of the ip address ...

```j
    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://mywebadress.com:3306/databasename";
    private static final String user = "username";
    private static final String pass = "password";
```

... the app will always put out an error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.Communications Exception: Communications link failure
> due to underlying exception: ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** *(and so
> on)*

I have always tested the connection between the web address and the Raspberry. There is no problem to retrieve e. g. html or php-files. There must be another problem.

Comment: Which version of MySQL Connector/J are you using? Recent versions do not work on Android because it uses Java features like named regex groups that are not available on Android. Also, creating JDBC connections from an Android application is a bad idea in general; it is better, safer and usually more performant to have a REST webservice mediate between your application and the database. And finally, please post the full exception stacktrace, not just the top as this hides information like exception causes.